# Add class depending on cookies after a div is generated from .load

Tags: jquery

I need to add a class to a div based on how cookies are set.  I have something like :

```
var tagPanelState = $.cookie('tagPanel');
var catPanelState = $.cookie('catPanel');

 if ((tagPanelState == "expanded") && (catPanelState == "expanded" ))
    {
        $('.tagTable').addClass( 'catBumpTwo' );         
    };
```

The problem is `$.tagTable` is loaded into the dom with ajax via :

```
var loadHistory = '<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>/tag/'+ tagPanelHistory + ' .tagTable';
$('.tagTable').detach();
$('#tagThumbs').load( loadHistory );
$('.tagTable').appendTo($('#ajaxTable'));
$('.tagTable').addClass( 'catBumpTwo' );
```

In neither case is `catBumpTwo` added unless I put an alert or breakpoints before it, then it is added.  So I guess I need to use something like  `.on` but the only way I have used that (or `.live` or `.delegate`) are with an event so I am not sure how I would addclass for this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do something after a call to load() completes, pass a callback to the load() function.  Here's an example, using variable names from your code:

```
$('#tagThumbs').load(loadHistory, function() {
    $('.tagTable').addClass('catBumpTwo');
});
```